# How to host a json file on the internet to consume with fetch?

Tags: javascript, json

I need to host a json file on the internet that allows GET and POST requests. I would consume data and send new data to this json, with javascript Fetch api would do the manipulations on the file.
For a college activity, for a website I'm creating.
would work like a "database".

No need to have security requirements.

Comment: Learn NodeJS and express and host it on Heroku for example

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project, and one that could be done in hundreds of different ways ... what's your *specific* question? Have a look at the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can use this api https://myjson.dit.upm.es/ to store your data json and request it with FETCH API. I hope I have solved your problem